# custom InfoWidnow shape Google maps v2 android

Tags: android, shapes, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I am able to change and fill custom controls in Info window contents by using InfoWindow Adapter. But, How can I change Info window shape??? How can I make it to circle or Oval from its default shape??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16318403/1168654 remove transperent theme from this ans and design layout.(what ever you want..)

Comment: we expect +1 vote instead of thanks....