# How to put drawable as a background on InfoWindow (Google Maps API v2 for Android)?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

This is my custom layout for my info window:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_infowindow" >
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_box"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView 
            style="@style/TexTitle"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView 
            style="@style/TextDistance"
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my custom adapter:

```
public class MapInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MapInfoWindowAdapter(Context context){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        // Getting view from the layout file
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_popup, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(marker.getTitle());

        TextView address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
        address.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

**However I want the custom drawable as the only background for my info window, How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Replace codes in `getInfoContents` with `getInfoWindow`. The difference between them is `getInfoContents` wraps your `View` in `ViewGroup` with default background.

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

    // Getting view from the layout file
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_popup, null);

    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(marker.getTitle());

    TextView address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    address.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your clarifying answer, however I was getting a NullPointerException using RelativeLayout as a root in my custom layout so I'm using a LinearLayout instead.

Comment: @IsaacCisneros That should probably be your original question then. This is a known issue. See this: [gmaps-api-issues](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4748).

Comment: @MaciejGórski I used the same code. It is working fine. I got trouble when click once again on the same window i hided the window. But in background the default info window shown remain. Have you removed that?

Comment: watsted 3 hours until I found your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this..

**custom_infowindow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#80000000" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:padding="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>


googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() 
{

        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0)
        {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
            return v;
        }

        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) 
        {
           return null;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the accepted answer i want to mention that if you still want the info window bubble you can use [this bubble layout library](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/BubbleLayout)

then you can set the bubble layout as background of your route view in the custom layout you are inflating.