# is possible to create a transparent info window with map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hieveryone, one question.I apply the background of infowindows like this:

`android:background="#55000000"`

but there seems to be a white background always behind it, is it possible to get rid of that?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Just extends InfoWindows and do your own maybe. Like that you can set any backgroud transparent

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put drawable as a background on InfoWindow (Google Maps API v2 for Android)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518338/how-to-put-drawable-as-a-background-on-infowindow-google-maps-api-v2-for-androi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your own InfoWindowAdapter for custom designing infoWindow

Example code

```
    private final View mWindow;

    public MarkerAdapter() {
        mWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker mark) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

        render(marker, mWindow);
        return mWindow;
    }

    private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
        int badge;
        // Use the equals() method on a Marker to check for equals. Do not
        // use ==.
        badge = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(badge);

        String title = marker.getTitle();
        TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));

        titleUi.setText(title);

        String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));

        snippetUi.setText(snippet);

    }

}
```

Then call it as

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MarkerAdapter());
```

Comment: thank you, it works. But the view in the getinfowindow instead of getinfocontents.

Comment: I was returning `null` in `getInfoWindow`. Returning my view did the job.