# How to place custom label under city names in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Maps API v2 for displaying the maps in android.

Is it possible to place temperature labels under each city name like what shown in below image.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get precise screen coordinates of cities names so you can't place temperature labels under each city name accurately. But you can hide all cities/towns names (and other labels) from map

[image: Map with cities names]

(please take a look at [Add a Styled Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling) for more details) and get cities coordinates and names from databases like [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/juanmah/world-cities) or [that](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities) and show city name and additional text as you wish.

To create map without cities names you can use[Styled map wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) interactive mode (move Labels seek bar to the left)

[image: Map without cities names]

and than click "Finish" button and copy-paste JSON like this:

```
[
  {
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [
      {
        "visibility": "off"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

into file in your project e.g. `src\main\res\raw\no_city_names_map_style.json`. Then you can apply this style to your map this way:

`mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.no_city_names_map_style));`

For placing text you can use [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker) with custom dynamically created icon that contains only text, e.g. like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562295/6950238) answer of [user2808624](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2808624/user2808624):

> ```
> public BitmapDescriptor createPureTextIcon(String text) {
>
>     Paint textPaint = new Paint(); // Adapt to your needs
>
>     float textWidth = textPaint.measureText(text);
>     float textHeight = textPaint.getTextSize();
>     int width = (int) (textWidth);
>     int height = (int) (textHeight);
>
>     Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
>     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
>
>     canvas.translate(0, height);
>
>     // For development only:
>     // Set a background in order to see the
>     // full size and positioning of the bitmap.
>     // Remove that for a fully transparent icon.
>     canvas.drawColor(Color.LTGRAY);
>
>     canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, textPaint);
>     BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image);
>     return icon;
> }
> ```

Then you can place marker with custom text on map this way:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(<city_location>)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createPureTextIcon("Name Temperature")))
    .anchor(0.5f, 1));
```