# How to make transparent background for CardView in android?

Tags: android, background, dialog, transparent, cardview

I tried to make a transparent background, but the solutions that I tried didn't work.

[The background color of the parts I marked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k41aX.png)

When I click a marker on the map this dialog should open with transparent background. How can I do it?

Comment: If you are using `InfoWindow` then you should try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045793/is-possible-to-create-a-transparent-info-window-with-map-v2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518338/how-to-put-drawable-as-a-background-on-infowindow-google-maps-api-v2-for-androi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a dialog, then please try

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

before calling `dialog.show()`

Comment: thank you it worked, with this way
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setView(R.layout.dialog_layout)
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));