# Issue with custom infowindow in Google Maps V2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps

Anyone know how to remove the edges of the custom infowindow

[image]

This is my XML of the infowindow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/negro"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image_mapa"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Las Flores"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/snippet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Resto bar"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descuento"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20% OFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/verde_habitues"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using an adaptar which implements InfoWindowAdapter

Thanks!

Comment: There is no padding o margin in anywhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put drawable as a background on InfoWindow (Google Maps API v2 for Android)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518338/how-to-put-drawable-as-a-background-on-infowindow-google-maps-api-v2-for-androi)

Answer (score 7):

The solution is on the adapter i nstead of overwriting *getInfoContents* overwrite *getInfoWindow*

```
public class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter
{
    private final View myContentsView;
    private Context ctx;

    public MyInfoWindowAdapter(View myContentsView, Context ctx)
    {
        this.myContentsView = myContentsView;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {


    TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());        


        return myContentsView;

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: hi i have same problem as in your answer it show the info window but it is not showing arrow from marker... please let me know the reason..

Comment: this sure solves the problem but also make the default "speech bubble" disappear. Is there any way to remove the padding which is coming while showing the 'title' in the "speech bubble"?