# How to display a variable in my info window on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to display my "double CO2Data" in my textView in my info window. I am not sure where and how I write that code. Does anyone have any tips or ideas on how to do that?

My MapsActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private boolean initiateApp;
double CO2data = 1.02;
double N2data = 0.002;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    initiateApp = true;


}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

/* Here we create the infoWindow **/
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

            return v;
        }

        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            //View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

            return null;

        }
    });

}




@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(0);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mCurrLocationMarker.showInfoWindow();

    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));


    //move map camera

    if(initiateApp){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
    }
    initiateApp = false;

    boolean contains = mMap.getProjection()
            .getVisibleRegion()
            .latLngBounds
            .contains(latLng);

    if(!contains){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }


}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Asking user if explanation is needed
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted. Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other permissions this app might request.
        // You can add here other case statements according to your requirement.
    }
}
}
```

My custom infowindow xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="110dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/infoText"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code that I used to for the info window

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
    return v;
}

public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

    //View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);

    return null;

}
});
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? Are you facing problem in setting info window text or problem in setting a double value in textview?

Comment: @Kunu I have problem in setting a double value in changing the textView in my MapsActivity. I tried adding 
private TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.infoText);
and then in my OnCreate method:
text.setText("Value" + CO2Data); But this crashes the app

Comment: Could you post the whole code? I can't see any info window in above question.

Comment: I just copy pasted the code that is under "Here we create the infoWindow" in MapsActivity.

Comment: @Kunu I just took the code from the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711522/how-to-change-the-custom-infowidnow-shape-of-the-google-maps-api-v2/16712599#16712599

Comment: Could you please add those code here in your question?

Comment: @Kunu now I added it :). I want to update the textView in the custom_infowindow with a double value.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your info window content code, right now you are returning null I guess

```
public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.infoText);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(CO2data));

    return v;

}
```

Comment: Now the app does not crash, but it does not display the value in the textView.

Comment: Now I got it to work! I should have put your code in the "setInfoWindowAdapter" method. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Happy to help you. Yeah as it is override method of the `InfoWindowAdapter` interface it must be inside that.