# How can inflate view personalized addmarker? gmaps

Tags: android, google-maps

The other day I asked, as fill from a cursor. I got on top of that focus all brands with the maximum zoom.
But now I have a problem and fill in the custom view, where there is title, description, and latitude and longitude.
It takes me head, I'm trying to look as filling sight, but each does so in a way. I am not able.
Here my code

**info_windows_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Esto es un titulo"
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="tv_descripcion"
        android:id="@+id/tv_descripcion"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_lng"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="lang" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**CajerosMaps**

```
    public class CajerosMaps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        Cursor cursor;
        MiCajeroOperacional mb;
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder;
        CameraUpdate cu;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cajeros_maps);
            mb = MiCajeroOperacional.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            cursor = mb.listar();
            mMap = googleMap;
            LatLng mark = null;

            List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<Marker>();


    int i = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            double lat = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("lat"));
            double lng = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("lng"));
            mark = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            Marker markCajero = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mark).title("Sucursal Nº" + i).snippet(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("direccion"))));
            // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mark), 15);
            markersList.add(markCajero);
            i++;
        }
        cursor.close();
        builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Marker m : markersList) {
            builder.include(m.getPosition());
        }
        int padding = 50;
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        mMap.moveCamera(cu);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to inflate custom view in info window??

Comment: yes, replace this part of code for custom view :              Marker markCajero = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mark).title("Sucursal Nº" + i).snippet(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("direccion"))));

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317224/custom-infowindow-with-google-maps-api-v2

Comment: I've already got, it cost me a lot, I followed the link I pasastes